# Distance between two distributions

Tags: time-series, probability, distributions, distance-functions

I am analyzing time-series data, and I would like to detect a significant change in data distribution. I already know about Bhattacharyya distance, but that requires histograms of equal-sized bins. What if I have histograms, but the bins are not equal-sized? I also have kernel density estimates, but once again, the sampling points are not the same. What is the best approach in this case?

Comment: Are you asking how to compute the Bhattacharyya distance between two estimated distributions (with the issues that you mentioned)? Or, are you asking more generally how to detect changes in time-series data?

Comment: I am asking how to compute the Bhattacharyya distance when bins are not equal sized. Alternatively, is there another algorithm that works even when the bins are different?